# Accidentally delete DPKG (exclui sem querer o DPKG)

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, dpkg

E: Sub-processo dpkg --set-selections retornou um código de erro (100)

```
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (100)
E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states
```

Comment: Please try to write the question in English. Automatic translation tools are usually good enough. Please also state your problem abd what you've done so far to solve it.

Comment: unintentionally delete the DPKG

E: Sub-processo dpkg --set-selections retornou um código de erro (100) E: Couldn't clean the currently selected dpkg states

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741466/edit) the original question instead. Error messages, commands etc. should be enclosed in the code brackets `{ }` in the top bar of the edit window. I translated now the message for you. The error message alone isn't enough to help you, please explain more completely what exactly you are doing, what command you give etc. when you receive this error. See [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Use `export LANG=C` before typing any command so their results are in English. And please describe (in English) what means "accidentally delete DPKG". Does that mean you don't have `/var/lib/dpkg` anymore? Something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.